# How to test a function composition with side effects without using mocks?

Tags: javascript, testing, functional-programming

I have a function, `MyComposedFunction`, which is the function composition of 3 functions the second function, `fn2`, performs a POST request (a side effect) using the result of `fn1` and passes this value to `fn3`.

```
const fn2 = async (fn1Result) => {
    const result = await fetch(fn1Result.url, fn1Result.payload);

    // some business logic

   return fn2Results;
};

const MyComposedFunction = compose(fn3, fn2, fn1);

// My Test
expect(MyComposedFunction('hello world')).toBe('expected result');
```

I'd like to avoid writing unit tests for `fn3`, `fn2`, and `fn1` and instead only test `MyComposedFunction`. My rationale is that it should not matter whether `MyComposedFunction` uses `compose(...)` or is one long giant function as long as `MyComposedFunction` works.

Is it possible to write a test for `MyComposedFunction` without having to mock `fn2`?

I would think that this must be a relatively common situation when trying to do functional programming in JavaScript but haven't been able to find a helpful resource so far.

Comment: A crucial aspect of FP is separating pure from impure code and trying to leave as much code as possible pure. Usually you achieve this goal by deferring the evaluation of effects as long as possible (with applicatives/monads, for instance). Now you can test both parts separately, but you still need mocks for the impure one.

Answer (score 0):

You can dependency inject fetch into your function like so

```
const fn2Thunk = (fetcher = fetch) => async (fn1Result) => {
    const result = await fetcher(fn1Result.url, fn1Result.payload);

    // some business logic

   return fn2Results;
};

const fetchMock = async () => ({ result: "blah" })
const MyComposedFunctionTest = compose(fn3, fn2Thunk(fetchMock), fn1);

// My Test
const result = await MyComposedFunctionTest('hello world')
expect(result).toBe('expected result');
```